# Unable to make dynamic module import work with module esnext in tsconfig in Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to make dynamic import work in my angular 5 application. As per this [github issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16675), the comment says that using `module: esnext` should make it work. This is my config

```
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "noEmitOnError": true,
  "target": "es2016",
  "module": "esnext",
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "sourceMap": true,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "declaration": false,
  "lib": [
    "es2016",
    "dom"
  ]
}
```

Note: Not having `es2016` in lib gives me errors because I am using `.find()` and `.includes` on Array's in my code.

I get this error when compiling

```
error TS1323: Dynamic import cannot be used when targeting ECMAScript 2015 modules.
```

Not sure why it still says targeting ECMA2015 modules when I have `module: esnext`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I figured this out. Turns out that it was a silly mistake and I was editing `tsconfig.json` in the root folder and there was another `tsconfig.app.json` in `src` folder that was overriding my settings.

Answer (score 0):

Update of tsconfig.app.json & will work

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "esnext",
        "baseUrl": "",
        "types": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I configured my `tsconfig.app.json`:

```
{
    "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
    "compilerOptions": {
        "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
        "target": "es2016",
        "module": "esnext",
        "baseUrl": "",
        "types": []
    },
    "exclude": [
        "test.ts",
        "**/*.spec.ts"
    ]
}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange

Comment: Also see this SO Meta post on Non-English content: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061